# Problem in using boost library with VS2019

Tags: c++, boost

Currently I am using boost library 1_54_0 in my project and it is working fine in VS2010.
But when I am upgrading the same project to VS2019 I am getting errors.

friend boost::shared_ptr boost::make_shared(); --> No issues
friend boost::shared_ptr boost::make_shared(std::string const & a1);--> error C2063 'boost::make_shared': not a function

Even I tried with the latest boost library 1_77_0. With that also same issue.
Please help in resolving the problem.

Comment: VS2019 has `std::shared_ptr`, which is the direct successor of `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: ***Currently I am using boost library 1_54_0 in my project and it is working fine in VS2010. But when I am upgrading the same project to VS2019 I am getting errors*** You can't link the boost 1.54 binaries from VS 2010 with VS 2019 anyways. Make sure that while upgrading that all third party decencies are replaced with binaries produced with a compatible compiler. VS 2019 is compatible with binaries from VS2015 to 2019 and no other version of msvc (except possibly the VS2022 beta).

Comment: Thank you @drescherjm, As you mentioned I tried using the latest boost library 1_77_0 as well. Still I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

> `boost::make_shared`: not a function

That is the correct error message. It's a function **template**. You can make every `make_shared<T>` template instantiation a friend, or just one specific instantiation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have instantiated as friend functions only. And I am using boost_1_77_0